# Is it possible to re-render a d3.js graph live?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

So I have a graph made with D3.js (v4), and it has a domain scale as such:

```
...
.domain([domainA, domainB})
...
```

`domainA` and `domainB` are both variables defined with a specific value like:

```
var domainA = 500;
var domainB = 1000;
```

There is a function in my HTML page which, when a button is pressed, updates the values of `domainA` and `domainB`. However, the domain scale of my graph does not change until I click on one of the bar graphs on the full graph.

I wanted to know how to be able to re-render the graph, to be able to set the domain scale immediately when the values of `domainA` and `domainB` are changed, and not have to click on one of the bars to update the graph.

Thanks, any help is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch new values with setInterval:

```
setInterval(()=> {
         if (domainValue !== domainValueOld){
            render()
         }
   }, 100)
```

At every 100 ms, the domainValue will be checked, and if it has changed the render function will be executed.

Comment: So in this, I would have to set domainValue and domainValueOld or are these preset?

Comment: You have to set them. It was only to show what you can do with setInterval

Comment: Alright, it seems as if to have worked. Thank you for introducing me to setInterval